# KMDF on Windows Server

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, device-driver, kmdf

A bit new to the world of Windows device drivers.  Using Visual Studio 2013 I create a new KMDF driver project.  The configuration manager has build configs for Windows 7, 8, 8.1, but none for the server OSes (WS 2008, 2012).

Question:  Which of these build targets, if any, are suitable for installation on Windows Server 2008/2012 since there are no specific build configs for them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered for me by Don Burn on MSDN, but I wanted to post the answer here for SO users:

Windows Server 2008 R2 == Windows 7

Windows Server 2012 == Windows 8

Windows Server 2012 R2 = Windows 8.1

As a rule you build for the earliest version of Windows you wish to support, and the driver will run on all versions after that.  There are special cases where there are new capabilities that you may want to take advantage of in the newer system, but that is the general approach.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/64b0a2af-f885-4a9d-8239-7a6de548b298/kmdf-on-windows-server?forum=wdk